# pandas cross sectional indexing - select multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

How can I select `count` and `50%` when slicing the multi index in pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'foo': [1,2,3], 'bar':[4,5,6], 'dt':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02']
})
df.groupby(['dt']).describe().loc[:, (slice(None), '50%'), (slice(None), 'count')]
```

fails with:

```
IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another lesser known way is using `axis` parameter to `.loc`,[see docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#basic-indexing-on-axis-with-multiindex):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'foo': [1,2,3], 'bar':[4,5,6], 'dt':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02']
})
df.groupby(['dt']).describe().loc(axis=1)[:, ['count','50%']]
```

Output:

```
             foo        bar     
           count  50% count  50%
dt                              
2020-01-01   2.0  1.5   2.0  4.5
2020-01-02   1.0  3.0   1.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `pd.IndexSlice`

```
ix = pd.IndexSlice
df.groupby(['dt']).describe().loc[:, ix[:, ['count', '50%']]]

Out[8]:
             bar        foo
           count  50% count  50%
dt
2020-01-01   2.0  4.5   2.0  1.5
2020-01-02   1.0  6.0   1.0  3.0
```